# How to detect if a number is a whole number or a float in C?

Tags: c, math, floating-point, integer

So I am new to C, and I mainly use it to make calculators for probability and stuff like that. My current project finds the increase and decrease of 2 values.

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//Variables

//Main Area
int main()
{
    float num1;
    float num2;
    float num3;
    float num4;
    float answer;
    //Scanning for the first number
    printf("\n Please Enter the first Value : ");
    scanf("%f", &num1);
    //scanning for the second number
    printf("\n Please Enter the second Value : ");
    scanf("%f", &num2);
    //calculating
    num3 = num1 - num2;
    num4 = num3 / num1;
    answer = num4 * 100;
    //Checking if the answer is an increase or decrease
    if (answer > 0) {
        printf("The answer has been decreasedby: %f\n", answer);
        printf("percent");
    } else {
        printf("The answer has been increased by: %f\n", answer * -1);
        printf("percent");
    }
  
    //Printing the answer
 
}
```

The output:

```
 Please Enter the first Value: 9                                                                                                                            
 Please Enter the second Value : 90                                                                                            
The answer has been increased and the final value is: 900.000000                                                               
percent
```

So I set all the values as `floats` rather than `int` because `int` only support whole numbers. But when I do get a whole number rather then displaying only the single number with no decimal points, it produces a number with the number and a bunch of zeros after the decimal point. Is there a way to detect if the number Is a whole number and just display that number?

Comment: Hmmm ... maybe if you compare `x - (int)x` with a small number suits you ... `if (x - (int)x < 0.000000001) /* x is (kinda) a whole number */;`

Comment: Ok I will try, but again how do I display only the first digits

Comment: Is this just an output-problem? Did you try `%.2f` or `%.2g` instead of `%f`?

Comment: When is `x` a whole number? `x = M_PI - 0.14159`? `x = M_PI - 0.1415926535`? `x = M_PI - 0.141592653589793`? `x = M_PI - 0.14159265358979323846`? `x = M_PI - 0.1415926535897932384626433`?

Comment: Oh, Prefer `double` when dealing with floating-point values.

Comment: Asking whether a number is a whole number or a float is like asking whether an animal is a dog or a mammal.

Comment: Read http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre], including exact input that reproduces the problem and the exact output the program produces. Formatting with `%f` does not normally provide “about thirty 0’s”, and that is not an adequate problem description, especially since the input needed to produce that output is not provided.

Comment: @EricPostpischil To be honest, the description "*about thirty 0's*" was my edit. Before it was "*30 0's*. I changed "30" to "thirty" because of danger of confusion with its output and the 30 would only be a feeling since it shouldn't in fact output thirty digits of the fraction part. This is pedantry but shall we/I remove the "*about*"?

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the answers. @pmg your second comment is kind of confusing. Is there a simpler way to interpret that. (Sorry only a beginner )

Comment: The land of floating-point numbers is full of unexpected surprises. Once you define something to be a `double` (or `long double` or `float`) the usual mathematical rules no longer apply (in corner / edge cases).

Comment: Why does code print negative `answer` as positive?

Comment: because it times it by -1 ?

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, Ok it wasn't 30 zeros but it was more then was intended. I will edit the question to show the output.

Comment: Lots of people have been saying I make the final answer positive even though it is negative, My reasoning is when the answer increases it shows a negative number which is kind of confusing for a user, so I wrote `The answer has been increased and the final value is: 900.000000                                                               
percent` so it was a bit more clear

Comment: @webetreesorg: That actual output makes a huge difference. “30 0's” would mean we are looking for a bug in your source code. “900.000000” is normal output for `%f` and means we are looking for a different formatting method. If you want to program computers well, learn to be exact and pay attention to details.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, thanks for the feedback, will be sure to have a bit more attention to my code!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compare `answer` to the return value of f.e. the [`floorf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/floor) function (header `math.h`) - `floorf()` since you dealing with a variable of type `float` - with `answer` passed as argument.

By doing so, you proof if `answer` contains an even decimal value.

For the output itself, Use a precision specifier (f.e. `.0`) which specifies the amount of digits in the fraction part and place it between the `%` and the `f` conversion specifier, For example `%.0f`.

The precision of `.0` specifies that you want to display no fraction part.

```
// Checking if the answer is an increase or decrease

if ( answer > 0 ) {

      if ( answer == floorf(answer) )     // If answer contains a decimal value.
          printf("The answer has been decreased and the final value is: %.0f\n", answer);
      else
          printf("The answer has been decreased and the final value is: %.3f\n", answer);
}
else {

      if ( answer == floorf(answer) )     // If answer contains a decimal value.
          printf("The answer has been increased and the final value is: %.0f\n", answer * -1);
      else 
          printf("The answer has been increased and the final value is: %.3f\n", answer * -1);     
}
```

---

**Side Notes:**

1. Note that floating-point often does not provide expected results:
   [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)
   So, it is possible that even this technique will not work at each and every use case.
2. Always check the return value of input functions such as `scanf()` if an input error occurred.
3. I used [`floorf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/floor), but [`ceilf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ceil), [`truncf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/trunc) or [`roundf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) could also be used to achieve the same effect.
4. `int main()` is deprecated. Use `int main(void)` instead which declares a full prototype for `main()`.
5. Since `answer` will be negative when reaching the `else` body, printing `answer * -1` will output a positive value, since `- * - = +`. Maybe this is not intended, so this just as a hint.

Comment: Does this work correctly for integers not exactly representable as a float? I don't think so, but FP math is tricky. If it doesn't, would `modff` work correctly? (also not sure about that one).

Comment: @Voo The problem has nothing to do about using `floorf()` or friends as suggested in my answer to answer the question given by OP. The problem is the float arithmetic in OP's example *before* any detection at all takes place. The comparison to the return value of `floorf()` is absolutely appropriate for what OP want to do. That it is susceptible is not my fault. The method by using `modff()` as suggested in chux's answer falls too if the arithmetic isn't well. It is a generic problem. Maybe the use of integer types would be better.

Comment: @Voo "*If it doesn't, would `modff` work correctly? (also not sure about that one).*" - No. As you can see, chux uses more or less the same algorithm with `fpart == 0.0` - He compares the fraction part to infinite 0. This will also not work if the fraction part isn't infinite 0 by an supposed fully even integer value due to the flawed floating arithmetic.

Comment: Yeah my error was worrying about the case of a float abc.xyz that is representable but abc would not be. While that could happen it wouldn't change the result.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there a way I can detect if the answer is a whole number and only display that number?

To detect if `float` is a whole number, use `modff()` to break a `float` into its whole number and fractional parts.

```
float f;
float ipart;
float fpart = modff(f, &ipart);
printf("%g is %s whole number.\n", f, fpart == 0.0 ? "a" : "not a");
```

An alternative to detecting "whole-ness", use `"%g"` to print floating point numbers with reduced output.  Yet this is insufficient unless the `"%g"` uses a higher precision - see below.

```
printf("%g\n", 2.0/3.0);  // 0.666667
printf("%g\n", 1234.0);   // 1234
```

---

Perhaps a step further with `"%g"`.  Use a *precision* wide enough to show any non-zero digits to the right of the `.` and let the specifier lop off the trailing zeros when the answer is a whole number.

```
printf("%.*g\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG, some_float);
printf("%.*g\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, some_double);
```

Comment: This is sneaky.

Comment: Congrats for 100k rep BTW 

Answer (score -1):

My way of checking involves :

```
if(num1 == (int)num1) // This checks whether num1 is integer
{
     //Do something
}
else
{
     //num1 is float
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but how do I display only the integer itself?

Comment: Just use `printf("%d",(int) num1);` Or you can use format specifier like `printf("%.0f",num1);` That number after **.** in format specifier is used to display number of decimal places using 0 will print 0 decimal digits

Comment: Try your test with the float number `2147483648`.

Comment: Lol , Just in case check with `num1 == (long long) num1`

Comment: Have a go at `18446744073709551616` then. Yes, that is a representable `float`. The point is, don't cook your own functions for things that already have well-tested library support. In this case, have a look at `roundf`.

Comment: How would you check if its an integer using `roundf`

Comment: See [RobertS's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62633318/430766).

Comment: This is simple test that works for those floats that represent an int exactly. The question is unclear enough that this is a reasonable answer to one possible interpretation of the question.

Comment: @Arshad `(long long) num1` and `(int) num1` risk undefined behavior (UB): "If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined" as the value of `num1` may be well outside the target integer type range.